# rsyslog ommail sends messages with empty bodies

Tags: rsyslog

I'm trying to send email from rsyslog (using the ommail module) on certain events, but no matter what I do the message bodies are always empty.

My configuration file says:

```
module(load="ommail")

template (name="mailBody"  type="string" string="RSYSLOG Alert\\r\\nmsg='%msg%'")
template (name="mailSubject" type="string" string="lti problem on %hostname%")

if $syslogseverity <= 4 and $syslogfacility-text == 'local1' then {
   action(type="ommail" server="localhost" port="25"
          mailfrom="obfuscated@obfuscated.com"
          mailto="obfuscated@obfuscated.com"
          subject.template="mailSubject")
}
```

This is copied from the example at https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/ommail.html

Messages are sent but the body is empty. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
module(load="ommail")

template (name="mailBody"  type="string" string="%msg%")
template (name="mailSubject" type="string" string="lti problem on %hostname%")

if $syslogseverity <= 4 and $syslogfacility-text == 'local1' then {
   action(type="ommail" server="localhost" port="25"
          mailfrom="obfuscated@obfuscated.com"
          mailto="obfuscated@obfuscated.com"
          subject.template="mailSubject"
          body.enable="on"
          template="mailBody")
}
```

See the `mailBody` template value `%msg%` and the parameters `body.enable="on"` and `template="mailBody"`.

Answer (score 0):

You must specifically set the template on the action clause (with template="mailBody"). This is missing from the example. You may also need body.enable="on" though this is supposedly the default.

```
module(load="ommail")

template (name="mailBody"  type="string" string="RSYSLOG Alert\\r\\nmsg='%msg%'")
template (name="mailSubject" type="string" string="lti problem on %hostname%")

if $syslogseverity <= 4 and $syslogfacility-text == 'local1' then {
   action(type="ommail" server="localhost" port="25"
          mailfrom="obfuscated@obfuscated.com"
          mailto="obfuscated@obfuscated.com"
          subject.template="mailSubject"
          template="mailBody")
}
```